# Load Report Builder into PHP page

Tags: php, sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

Is there any possible way to Load and view Microsoft SQL server 2012 report builder in a PHP application?

Comment: isn't it a desktop application ? o_0 does it have a web interface?

Comment: Why exactly would you want to do that? If you tell us what your requirements are, someone might know how to approach the problem in a different way.

Comment: Sure report builder? Not report viewer?

Comment: @MaxLeske : i want to do this because i'm using web interface system and i need to let the user use the report from inside the application <br /> so he can enter the parameters,  i used to do this with ASP.net and it works fine and perfectly but now im using PHP and i have no idea how to do this,i asked a friend who has experience in PHP and he told that it's doable but he don't know how exactly to do it

Comment: Well, how did you do it in ASP.net then? Either that application generated the web pages for you, or there's an API you can talk to...